# What's wrong with my VBA code (I'm getting runtime error 9)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've looked around and found that the "runtime error 9 subscript out of range" error usually has to do with arrays.  However, I'm not sure how to interpret the answers I've found to best suite my code.

I have a simple function that I wrote to pull the first and last names out of a field, I then found that the field had a few Nulls in it and tried to compensate by changing from a String to Variant decleration.

I've gotten this to work without an error with similar code... but not with this code.

My code is as follows:

```
    Function FLastName(ByVal lnIn As Variant) As Variant
    Dim astrFullName() As String
    If IsNull(lnIn) Then
        FLastName = Null
    Else
        ReDim astrFullName(2) 'This is a new concept to me... not sure if I really need this
        astrFullName = Split(lnIn, ",")
        FLastName = astrFullName(0)

    End If
End Function
```

Thanks in advance for your insights and assistance.

EDIT: 
I found that the issue is that the array doesn't like the Null value in some of the name fields... I thought that the following line would fix that:

```
If IsNull(lnIn) Then
    FLastName = Null
```

But apparently I was wrong.
Anyone have some advice on what I've found thus far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!

Allen Browne (who is totally awesome) has a "ParseWord" function available on his site that takes care of what I need to accomplish.

It can be found here:  http://allenbrowne.com/func-10.html

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need to `ReDim` ... and you dont even have to `Dim` it as an Array.

```
Function FLastName(ByVal lnIn As Variant) As Variant
    Dim astrFullName
    If IsNull(lnIn) Then
        FLastName = Null
    Else
        astrFullName = Split(lnIn, ",")
        FLastName = astrFullName(0)
    End If
End Function
```

PS: Assuming that lnIn would contain a comma separated string ... else you may have to put a check.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response Pankaj Jaju.  I still get the subscript out of range error.  I've tried compacting and repairing and I've even tried commenting out the Dim with no added success.  Also, the "lnIn" variable is a comma separated string.

Comment: Ahh ... that was my mistake. You dont really have to initialize `astrFullName` as string. I have updated the code. Check now.

Comment: I now get a type mismatch error on the "astrFullName = Split(lnIn, ",")" line

Comment: Works for me though. What is the value that you are sending in lnln?

Comment: The field was NULL and that's why I was getting errors.  I was pulling from a table where not all names had to have an entry.  Regardless, thanks for your input.

Comment: The code has null check. Isn't this working for you.